# The best estimate of age of a person in social network

Tags: estimation, modeling, graph-theory, social-network, age

Suppose that we have any social network (i.e. we know who is a friend of whom) and for some nodes in the network (i.e. the users), we also know their age (but not for everyone, as in a real network).

Now the question is, if we have no other information, what is the best way to estimate the age of any person in the network? Obviously, people tend to have friends with a similar age so we can somehow use this infomation.

Comment: I am not too sure because I do not know what data you have. But to me it seems that basically you need to deal with missings, hence maybe you could use an imputation method like multiple imputation. I find it difficult to give a more detailed answer not knowing what the data is.